# JQuery.on() piles up

Tags: jquery, events

Why

```
JQuery.on('sameEventName.',function(){...});
```

piles up depending how many time the code works? And is there a way to prevent this??

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xe3umjf/2/)

Comment: Why do you expect adding two handlers to not add two handlers?

Comment: Actually handlers run in a modal form(coming from a remote source via ajax) in order to close the form after a successfull submission and to reload some datatable. I'm saving data one after another and every time i call the form modal,  .on('..') code runs.. And refreshes the datatable twice or more unnecessarily..

Comment: You should probably update your question to more accurately reflect your scenario, including actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to achieve behaviour where even with multiple clicks, only 1 event listener is present. Although the following it's not ideal, but it's the most simple workaround. Use [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove previous event listener.

```
$(document).off('aCustomEventName');
$(document).on('aCustomEventName', function(){...});
```

Full snippet:

```js
$('#set').on('click', function () {
    $(document).off('aCustomEventName');
    $(document).on('aCustomEventName', function (event) {
        alert('event caught');
    });
});

$('#trigger').on('click', function () {
    $(document).trigger("aCustomEventName");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Click on Set Listener button a few times then click on the Trigger Event button..
</div>

<button id="set">Set Listener</button>
<button id="trigger">Trigger Event</button>
```

And also [fixed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/3xe3umjf/3/) (same as snippet).